# Why does the use of Jeffrey distributions does not satisfy the likelihood principle?

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference, bayesian, binomial-distribution, maximum-likelihood

It's commonly used as an example, the Bernoulli experiments seen as a binomial and negative binomial random sample, with a posterior distributions $$\Pi _J ^1 (\theta) \propto\theta^ {-\frac{1}{2} }(1-  \theta) ^{-\frac{1}{2}}  \not\propto \theta ^{-1} (1-  \theta) ^{-\frac{1}{2}} \propto\Pi _J ^2 (\theta),$$ with a prior the Jeffrey's distribution, but why Jeffrey's distributions does not satisfy the likelihood principle?

If you could clarify this to me, I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

(Your $\Pi_J^1$ and $\Pi_J^2$ are the usual Jeffreys *prior* distributions in the binomial and negative binomial experiments, respectively, but you've mistakenly called them *posterior* distributions.)

Let (["binomial"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)) Experiment 1 observe the number of *successes* in $12$ trials, and let (["negative binomial"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)) Experiment 2 observe the number of *trials* required to get $3$ successes. Now suppose that the outcome of Experiment 1 is $3$ successes, and that the outcome of Experiment 2 is $12$ trials. Then, *for both experiments*, the [likelihood function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_principle#Example) is proportional to 
$$\theta^3(1-\theta)^9.
$$
Therefore, according to the [Likelihood Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_principle), these outcomes of the two experiments must lead to exactly the same inferences about $\theta$. *But the use of Jeffreys priors violates this*, because the Jeffreys prior for Experiment 1 is proportional to $\theta^{-1/2}(1-\theta)^{-1/2}$, whereas the Jeffreys prior for Experiment 2 is proportional to $\theta^{-1}(1-\theta)^{-1/2}$, producing two different posterior distributions (hence different inferences about $\theta$) in the two cases.